# use android repo tool with github or gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab, git-repo

I'm trying to mirror every android repo to my gitlab account.
After I imported ALL of repositories, I tried to use git-repo (repo tool from google) to build android from source.

I changed these line in my default.xml manifest:

```
<remote  name="aosp" fetch="https://android.googlesource.com" review="android-review.googlesource.com" revision="refs/tags/android-5.1.1_r37" />
```

to this:

```
<remote name="aosp" fetch="https://gitlab.com/android_source/" review="android-review.googlesource.com" revision="refs/tags/android-5.1.1_r37"/>
```

I also changed every project name. for example:

```
<project path="dalvik" name="platform/dalvik" groups="pdk-cw-fs" remote="aosp"/>
```

to this:

```
<project path="dalvik" name="platform_dalvik" groups="pdk-cw-fs" remote="aosp"/>
```

now, here is my problem. when I run repo command

```
repo sync
```

I get these type of errors:

```
Fetching projects:   0% (1/541)  Fetching project platform_prebuilts_ndk.git
fatal: Couldn't find remote ref refs/tags/android-5.1.1_r37
fatal: Couldn't find remote ref refs/tags/android-5.1.1_r37
error: Cannot fetch platform_prebuilts_ndk.git

error: Exited sync due to fetch errors
```

Whats wrong??

you can see [default.xml](https://gitlab.com/android_source/tmp/commit/9580bb3b363a5db81c49dacd7bde12d6c644cfe4) and [changed](https://gitlab.com/android_source/tmp/raw/4fd75c634c9f8e2d651c937bea5df0fd49c9cefd/README.md) one.

**EDIT:**
I found a solution but I don't like it.
I changed this:

```
<remote name="aosp" fetch="https://gitlab.com/android_source/" review="android-review.googlesource.com" revision="refs/tags/android-5.1.1_r37"/>
```

to this:

```
<remote name="aosp" fetch="ssh://git@gitlab.com/android_source/" review="android-review.googlesource.com" revision="refs/tags/android-5.1.1_r37"/>
```

now I can fetch using git_repo tools. But this is odd. other people should be able to clone my repo.

Comment: Hi, did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that's what you need, but here it goes.

---

If you want to mirror your repo, you should:

1. Click on **Create New Project**
2. Import it and mirror:

[image: Mirror repo on GitLab]

This way GitLab will update the mirrored repo with the upstream automatically.

Hope to have helped!

Comment: Thanks but I have problem with git-repo tool, not gitlab.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Hopefully someone else will come up with an answer to your question. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you can clone via ssh and not via https is probably because you configure GitLab projects as private and not public

I try to browse you personal gitlab group and, in fact, I cannot browse any project (however maybe it's just because you delete them, the question is, in fact, quite old, but maybe my answer may be useful to other too)

Answer (score 0):

First, I have to say that cloning all android-related projects is more a research idea than something useful for anyone else. It might be nice to understand the context a bit better.

Unfortunately, I cannot see the linked manifests as `https://gitlab.com/android_source/tmp` does not exist anymore ([amonthedeamon mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45601518) this in a previous answer).

By default, the `repo` command uses a specific URL and path to retrieve the manifest. In order to use your manifest, you need to provide it in the `repo init` ([ref](https://source.android.com/docs/setup/create/repo#init)) command.

1. Add your manifest to a repository - it seems, you have done this.
2. Use the `-u` and optional `-m` and `-b` arguments to point to the manifest

In your case, this would be

```bash
repo init -u https://gitlab.com/android_source/tmp.git
repo sync
```

Then, `repo sync` will go through the projects run `git clone` with the remote URL. I assume you are there, but I am not sure.

Assuming that you have cloned all repositories into `android_source`, they should now be available via your git prefix `https://gitlab.com/android_source/`. Git will now try to clone from `https://gitlab.com/android_source/{projectname}`, which does not seem to work.

If `ssh://git@gitlab.com...` works and `https://gitlab.com...` does not, I assume, a normal `git clone` does not work for the `https` URL. With a current version of git, you should be prompted for username and password. With [credentials](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials), you should be able to store that information

There are a couple of suggestions

- Switch to a more recent version of git that
  supports https authentication
- Make your projects public - see 
  [amonthedeamon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45601518)
- Change the `fetch` in your manifests to the prefix that works for you

  ```
  - <remote name="aosp" fetch="https://gitlab.com/...
  + <remote name="aosp" fetch="ssh://git@gitlab.com/...
  ```

  Note that this might not work for others, if the project is not public.
- Authenticate via https using a token: change the fetch `https` URLs to use a token or a username / password

I haven't used this myself, but you can also override the URLs via a [local manifest](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/+/HEAD/docs/manifest-format.md#local-manifests). Not sure if this only adds/removes project, or if you can actually override individual properties with a local configuration.